# Ecommerce App, what to do if payment gateway completes the transaction, but our server fails to store the returned data

Tags: android, rest, spring-boot, e-commerce

We are developing an ecommerce app using android as frontend and spring-boot as backend (using REST APIs).  For most of the payment gateways that we played around (paytm, cashfree etc.), the execution-flow is something like this.
1) Upon selecting the order, the android app requests a checksum and orderid from the merchant server.
2) Using the checksum and the order-id, the android app calls the payment-gateway APIs to perform the transaction and provides the callback (named A) to the payment-gateway.
3) The payment-gateway upon successfull transaction calls the callback A and returns to our android app supplying to it the arguments like order-id, transaction-id, date etc.
4) Our android app, then sends a HTTP POST REST api request to our merchant server to store all the details supplied by the payment gateways.

My question is how should be the MVC design when step 3) has succeeded but somehow the step 4) fails possibly because some issue connecting to the merchant server.

Option 1) Store this returned data from payment-gateway in the device itself, and keep polling the merchant server until the data is stored in the backend.
Option 2) When android app requests the merchant-server for the checksum and order-id, the merchant-server returns the checksum and orderId and waits for some specific amount of time, and after that time-period is expired, it directly communicates with the payment-gateway and check the transaction status using the order-id that it generated. 
Does option 2) violates any RESTful standard ? Is there any other better design?

Answer (score 1):

Most PGs also request a [notifyURL](https://docs.cashfree.com/docs/web/guide/#request-parameters) parameter from the app. This notifyURL will be a call from our servers to your app servers with all the details about a transaction (transaction status, amount, etc.)

So, your app server gets updated either through (4) or through this notifyURL (let's call it (5)). In any case invoking the checkStatus for a PG directly from your client app is not a good idea.